# CORBA OMG IDL to JSON/protobuf converter

Tags: json, protocol-buffers, corba, idl

Is there an existing library that is able to do this conversion to either JSON or protobuf?

Comment: It would help when you could add what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @pepel, have you solved the issue? I also need such a converter, may be commercial...

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of a existing library that does this. We have some JSON to IDL conversion support in our [AXCIOMA](http://www.axcioma.com) product but that is not full IDL support. One option is to create your own IDL to JSON/protobuf code generator, by using a generic IDL compiler front end this could be done, see for example [RIDLC](http://www.remedy.nl/products/ridlc.html).